# Breaking visualisation of images in test set of Cityscapes

Tags: python-imaging-library, imshow

I am working on `Cityscapes` dataset. But I have a problem to visualise the rgb masks in test set. Something that I am doing is as follows:

Reading the masks from the Root:

```py
root_path = './Baysian_Seg/Inputs/Cityscapes/test_labels'
mask_root = os.path.join(root_path,'ex_test_labels')

berlin_mask_list= sorted(os.listdir(os.path.join(mask_root,'berlin')))

mask_lists = ['berlin_000010_000019_gtFine_color.png',
 'berlin_000010_000019_gtFine_instanceIds.png',
 'berlin_000010_000019_gtFine_labelIds.png',
 'berlin_000010_000019_gtFine_polygons.json']

mask1 = Image.open(os.path.join(mask_root,'berlin',mask_lists[0]))

plt.imshow(mask1)
```

But I would get only a black image. I do not know where I am making mistake. I did the same for training and validation sets and I could visualise the masks correctly. I would appreciate any help.

P.S. I also tried to convert the `PIL` mask using : `maks1.convert('RGB')`, but it also did not help.

Comment: Please provide the images which fail.

Comment: It was solved. Indeed there wasn't any mask for the test set. I wrote to Cityscape team. And they told if I want to test the performance of my model on test set I should do that on their server.

Answer (score 0):

You can't test cityscapes, the test dataset is not public.So the images in test set are all black.